# Android Bluetooth LE API

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I know that Bluetooth Low Energy is now supported with Android 4.3. I also read that this is because Google and Broadcom developed an update for the Bluedroid Bluetooth Stack.

So I wonder if Android BLE APIs are supported for all Smartphones with Android 4.3 or only for those which have a Broadcom Bluetooth chipset.

Are these APIs compatible with Motorola devices??

Thanks!

Comment: Samsung has dropped its stack and the Motorola one never provided enough functionality. But you don't want to try the new one yet either. There are serious issues with the stack that make it impossible to connect to some devices. E.g. Apple's devices. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58725

Comment: Have Motorola released any updates for 4.3 yet?  If not then the answer is clearly no...  If yes then get a device and try the btle sdk sample app for a start.